# Why does $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{-x^2+1}} = \pi$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, trigonometry

Can you please show me the process that determines $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{-x^2+1}} = \pi$ ? Unfortunately I only know that the derivative of $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is equal to the integrand of that, but I don't actually know what to do with it. Can you help me?

Comment: [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

Comment: Do not use displaystyle when formatting the title.

Comment: @amWhy Why not? I always do, specially for integrations.

Comment: @PrimeMover I've found some discussion on meta [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-rm-latex-in-question-titles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you know that $$\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^2+1}},$$ you are already most of the way there.  This tells you that $$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{-x^2+1}} = \sin^{-1}(1) - \sin^{-1}(-1) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \pi.$$

This is due to the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), which says that for a continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]$, with antiderivative $F$, then $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a).$$

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I think this is an answer which helps the OP understand the process. Naming the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and then showing how it works through the example.

Answer (score 5):

You are right in saying that indeed, ${\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = \arcsin(x)}$. Now, you need to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which says that
$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = F(b) - F(a)
$$
where $F$ is a function satisfying
$$
F'(x) = f(x)
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Not sure why I've been downvoted? I didn't give an answer, I told OP what theorem they should be using

Answer (score 4):

Denote $x = \sin(t)$.

Because $-1 \le x \le 1$ then $-\frac{\pi}{2} \le t \le \frac{\pi}{2}$. We have:
\begin{align}
I &=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^2+1}}dx \\
&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-(\sin(t))^2+1}} d\sin(t)\\
&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos(t)}{\cos(t)} dt\\
&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1 dt\\
I&=\pi. \\
\end{align}

Comment: I rather like this answer. It tells you how to work out the solution, rather than applying prior knowledge and some fancy theorem. Unless my calculus is rustier than I realise and I'm missing something which the 5 downvoters spotted?